# autofocus on input in bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 to create a modal box. I want to have it `autofocus` on the `input` area. I tried with jQuery, but I don't know, what is the problem?

JavaScript:

```
$('#click').click(function () {
    $('input').focus()
});
```

Here is a [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48zceqnw/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48zceqnw/1/). When using the bootstrap modal window there are a number of [custom events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events) you can use. one of those is `shown.bs.modal` wich runs after a modal is fully shown (and your input field is focusable). Remember that the event will be triggered on the modal, not on whatever opened the modal.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('input').focus();
})
```

Comment: [with any luck this will be automatic in bootstrap 4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22402)

Answer (score 3):

This may be hard code but add a Timeout function to focus it.
The fact is the modal isn't here yet so the browser can't focus an element in it.

```
$('#click').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('input').focus() 
  },500);
});
```

Comment: Thnx tektiv, but i think Erik solution it better :)

Comment: yup, the "shown.bs.modal" event fires "after the modal has been made visible to the user"

Answer (score 0):

I am also use this code

```
<script>
    function setFocusOnModal(){
        $('#searchModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#q').focus();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Where **#searchModal** is modal div ID and **#q** is input element ID

Use this code in button

```
<button type="button" onclick="setFocusOnModal()">Open Modal</button>
```